valentina studio form design how to programatically add values to a listview?
ListView in Valentina Studio forms design seems to be set up ONLY to list items from a view, query, custom (manually entered) list.
QT methods like listView.addItem() do not work.
How do I take values entered in a lineEdit object and add these to the listView?
[... without having to create a temporary table!]
The listView scope prevents me accessing and updating objects from outside the listView object.
Any ideas how I can add value programatically to the listView?
Thanks!!!
I tried using QT methods like .addItem .add .populate . No good.
I tried initializing variables in the create object signal and accessing these outside the lineEdit object. No good.
I have not yet tried using a temporary table, which seems like overkill for managing a simple list of values.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

A Valentina Studio developer confirmed via email that these methods do not currently work. Programmatically changing a liveview may be included in a future release.
